# Getting Environment Variables Of An User By Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, environment-variables, subprocess

I have defined an environment variable by adding `export TEST1=VAL1` line into `/home/username/.bashrc` file.

This variable is listed when `printenv` command is used on terminal on my user account. But it is not listed when the following python code is used:

```
variables = subprocess.check_output("printenv", shell=True, executable='/bin/bash').decode()
```

What is the solution for listing this variable by using Python.

```
OS: Debian-like Linux, Python: 3.9
```

Example code for running terminal commands in python:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('test.ui')
window1 = builder.get_object('window1')

class Signals:
    def on_window1_destroy(self, widget):
        Gtk.main_quit()

builder.connect_signals(Signals())

import subprocess
variables = subprocess.check_output("/bin/bash -l -c printenv", shell=True).decode()
f = open("/tmp/env.txt","w")
f.write("%s" % (variables))
f.close()

window1.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

GUI file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="default_width">300</property>
    <property name="default_height">300</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <child internal-child="selection">
          <object class="GtkTreeSelection"/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429232/why-no-such-non-interactive-version-of-bashrc#429238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With shells, there is a difference between login and non login execution (see `man bash`).

`executable` attribute does not accept parameters, just an executable.

So try:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python
import subprocess
variables = subprocess.check_output("/bin/bash -c printenv", shell=True).decode()
f = open("/tmp/env.txt","w")
f.write("%s" % (variables))
f.close()
```

Output do not contains `TEST1` variable.

With bash `-l` option:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python
import subprocess
variables = subprocess.check_output("/bin/bash -l -c printenv", shell=True).decode()
f = open("/tmp/env.txt","w")
f.write("%s" % (variables))
f.close()
```

Output contains `TEST1` variable.

Comment: Both of the codes you wrote list the variable (the variable in the .bashrc file) if Python code is run from terminal. But none of them list the variable if they are run in a Python application/IDE. Other variables are list.

Comment: I have updated my code with an output to a file. It's work fine. First code, without `-l` bash option, `TEST1` is not visible. Second code, with `-l` bash option, `TEST1` is visible. I have created a launcher on my desktop for the Python script outside a terminal

Comment: I have added an example Python code and a simple GUI file for trying. The code you wrote did not work in my code. What is the reason for this? It lists the variable only if this code is called with terminal.

Comment: Ok. I see. In my `~/.bash_profile`, I have three lines for loading `~/.bashrc` like this : `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi`. Do you have those lines ? If not, put your `export ...` command in your `~/.bash_profile` file

Comment: Shell login explanation is too long for a comment. See `man bash`, "Invocation" section (man page : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#INVOCATION).
Also, about the creation of default files during creation of new user, generally with `useradd` command (man page : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/useradd.8.html). This command is also known as `adduser`. It's depends on your system, your distribution.